# Is there a way to control what can be imported in each package and file in python (fastapi)?

Tags: python, import, format, controls

For a large API project we are trying to enforce a folder structure and what package is allowed to be imported from other packages. Is there a package that can check this for you to be used in git pre-commit or CICD?

For example:

- views are allowed to import anything
- services are not allowed to import from views
- repositories are not allowed to import services

In Java i know there is a package called checkstyle that does this with [ImportControl](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/config_imports.html#ImportControl). Where it basically checks for a regex in each file.

Is there something similar in some python package ?

Comment: Google "python import linter".  This looks promising: https://import-linter.readthedocs.io/

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it. You *may* be able to get help on the [softwarerecs.se] Stack Exchange, but *please* read through their [help center](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) **first** to ensure your question is on topic there.